# Mysql query with multiple joins, first table repeats incorrectly

Tags: mysql, join

Say I have 3 tables:

**person:**

- person_id
- first_name
- last_name

**person_company:**

- person_id
- company_id

**company_address:**

- company_address_id
- company_id
- address_id

I have a mysql query that is as such:

```
SELECT * FROM person 
JOIN (
    person_company, 
    company_address
) 
ON ( 
    person.person_id = person_company.person_id 
    && person_company.company_id = company_address.company_id 
)
```

However, when I use the query I have the first entry in the first table repeat about 20 times, and then after that a few "clumps" as well. The issue is that this is creating an incorrect row, like John Smith doesn't work for company A, B, C and D.

I think the issue may be something to do with an assumption I am making that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Your JOIN syntax is a bit odd, you may have better results by joining tables one at a time.  I also added in aliases to the tables, though that is not 100% needed it can help if you join the same table multiple times.

```
SELECT 

    -- Probably best too select specific fields here as, for example,
    -- person_id exists in both person and person_company
    p.person_id,
    p.first_name,
    p.last_name,
    c.company_id,
    c.company_address_id,
    c.address_id     

FROM person AS p

-- First up join person_company to person as your query indicates an n:1 there
INNER JOIN person_company AS pc
    ON pc.person_id = p.person_id

-- Next join company_address to person_company, again as your query indicates n:1
INNER JOIN company_address ca
    ON ca.company_id = pc.company_id
```

If that still doesn't work, then the problem is in your data instead of the query!

Comment: Yeah sorry, I was using * just while I piece the join together, then I  replace it with the values I want. Also, what does "indicates n:1." is that a multiple to one relationship?

Comment: Correct, 1:1 == 1 to 1 relationship.  n:1 == multiple/many to one.  n:m == many to many relationship (usually achieved using a 3rd linking table to link the 2 tables together)

Answer (score 1):

I don't recognise your `JOIN` syntax. How does this work?

```
SELECT *
FROM person
JOIN person_company ON person.person_id = person_company.person_id
JOIN company_address ON person_company.company_id = company_address.company_id
```

Comment: I'll check that out. I'm self-teaching for JOINs and I got my syntax from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: That results in the same thing my syntax creates.

Comment: That's reassuring in a way, but doesn't really help. Are you completely sure about your data? Can you try to reduce to the minumum set of data that exhibits the problem and then add that dataset to your question?

Comment: I can try to whip an example up, it's all private information so I'm going to need time to make it anonymous.

Comment: Hey nurdglaw, sorry. Yours is actually different than mine and correct. It originally looked like it was flooding my table the same way, but it turns out one of the companies *actually* has 15 addresses!

Comment: Yeah, once I can more robustly confirm that it's working I'll edit my main post with the solution.